# turning a character vector into a single row dataframe in R

Tags: r

I have a vector that I want to turn into a single row dataframe, this code works:

```
vec <- c("a","b","c","d","e") 
df<- as.data.frame(t(as.data.frame(vec)))
```

but is so clunky, does anyone have a more elegant (and preferably less computationally expensive) solution

Comment: maybe `data.frame(as.list(vec))`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This might be one way :

```
data.frame(matrix(vec, 1))

#  X1 X2 X3 X4 X5
#1  a  b  c  d  e
```

---

Or changing your approach to this instead.

```
data.frame(t(vec))
```

Answer (score 4):

We can also do

```
as.data.frame.list(vec)
```